# What am I doing wrong with this code for hackerrank?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, function, stdout

I have been coding this problem for HackerRank and I ran into so many problems. The problem is called "Plus Minus" and I am doing it in Python 3. The directions are on https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/plus-minus/problem. I tried so many things and it says that "there is no response on stdout". I guess a none-type is being returned. Here is the code.:

```
def plusMinus(arr):
p = 0
neg = 0
z = arr.count(0)
no = 0

for num in range(n):
    if arr[num] < 0:
        neg+=1
    if arr[num] > 0:
        p+=1
    else:
        no += 1
    continue
return p/n
```

Comment: I think you need to print rather than return, and take input as specified in the problem statement.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

Comment: Do you happen to know why I need to print rather than return?

Comment: The problem says you should print three lines in `Output Format`.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for the clarification. Your good at analyzing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The following are the issues:**

1) variable `n`, which represents length of the array, needs to be passed to the function `plusMinus`

2) No need to maintain the extra variable `no`, as you have already calculated the zero count. Therefore, we can eliminate the extra `else` condition.

3) No need to use `continue` statement, as there is no code after the statement.

4) The function needs to print the values instead of returning.

**Have a look at the following code with proper naming of variables for easy understanding:**

```
def plusMinus(arr, n):

    positive_count = 0
    negative_count = 0
    zero_count = arr.count(0)

    for num in range(n):
        if arr[num] < 0:
            negative_count += 1
        if arr[num] > 0:
            positive_count += 1

    print(positive_count/n)
    print(negative_count/n)
    print(zero_count/n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())

    arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    plusMinus(arr, n)
```

Answer (score 0):

The 6 decimals at the end are needed too :

```
Positive_Values = 0
Zeros = 0
Negative_Values = 0

n = int(input())

array = list(map(int,input().split()))

if len(array) != n:
    print(f"Error, the list only has {len(array)} numbers out of {n}")

else:
    for i in range(0,n):
        if array[i] == 0:
            Zeros +=1
        elif array[i] > 0:
            Positive_Values += 1
        else:
            Negative_Values += 1

Proportion_Positive_Values = Positive_Values / n
Proportion_Of_Zeros = Zeros / n
Proportion_Negative_Values = Negative_Values / n

print('{:.6f}'.format(Proportion_Positive_Values))
print('{:.6f}'.format(Proportion_Negative_Values))
print('{:.6f}'.format(Proportion_Of_Zeros))
```